# Using SQL datareader to set variables to a label

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have spent so long on figuring this out however cant seem to resolve the problem. I am using MySql and Visual Basic.

I am using the select statement to get the variables i need, then using data reader to loop through, get the variables (to string) and finally set these to text labels which I am using in a form. I am sure I am following the correct procedure for this, but this does not seem to bring back results.

If anybody could help me i would be very much appreciated. The code I have is below;

```
    lblName.Text = Form1.topicName

    MyConnString = "Database=case management system;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password="abc"
    Dim MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection(MyConnString)
    Dim MySelectQuery As String = "SELECT topic_id, topic_name, description, useful_links, employee_id, date "             
       & "FROM knowledge_base "
       & "WHERE topic_name = '" & lblName.Text & "'"
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(MySelectQuery)
    myCommand.Connection = MySqlConn
    MySqlConn.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    While mydata.Read()
        labelDescription.Text = mydata.Item("description").ToString
        labelLinks.Text = mydata.Item("useful_links").ToString
    End While
    mydata.Close()
    myCommand.Connection.Close()
    MySqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: why are you using ExecuteNonQuery() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line containing `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.  You are doing query!

Also, the labels (descriptions and links) will only contain the last data from the last row returned.

Adding text input directly to a SQL command allows a SQL injection attack.  You should use sql parameters.  See http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: I have removed this, and still no luck?

Comment: Did the query return anything?  Check `mydata.HasRows`.

Comment: What do you mean will only contain the last data from the last row. The statement I am using should return only one row so how can i get it to return just this data? Thanks.

Comment: Now im even more confused.. My msgbox wont show up during mydata.read()
  While mydata.Read()
            If mydata.HasRows = True Then
                MsgBox("Yes", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
            Else
                MsgBox("No", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
            End If
            labelDescription.Text = mydata.Item("description").ToString
            labelLinks.Text = mydata.Item("useful_links").ToString
        End While

Comment: put the if condition and your msg alerts above while condition

Comment: Still no luck! Doesnt seem to be bringing any results back if there is a row or not.

Comment: what is mydata.HasRows returned for you,does it have rows?

Comment: No doesnt return any rows? Which means there must be something wrong with my data reader?

Comment: yes,check the Query once again and see what it returns in the database

Comment: Thank you all so much. It is finally working!! Spelling mistake in variable as well as the need to remove ExecuteNonQuery. Thank You.