# How to solve "No query in datareader" error?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Consider the following code :

```
 answer = today.AddDays(356)
 Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("Insert into UserScanner (Username,Password,Address,Contact,SubStart,SubEnd,Active) VALUES('" & txtbox_username.Text.Trim & "','" & txtbox_password.Text & "','" & txtbox_add.Text & "','" & txtbox_contact.Text & "','" & today.ToString & "','" & answer.ToString & "',1)", Connection)
 command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
 MsgBox("Profile Successfuly Saved")
 Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand("Select * From userscanner WHERE Username = '" & txtbox_username.Text & "' ", Connection)
 command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Dim dr1 As MySqlDataReader
 dr1 = command2.ExecuteReader
 dr1.Read()
 Dim id As Integer = .Item(0)
 Dim Username As String = .Item(1)
 Dim command3 As New MySqlCommand("Insert into Trasnsaction (ID,Username,Description,Date) VALUES('" & id & "','" & Username & "','Register Account','" & today & "')", Connection)
 command3.ExecuteNonQuery()
 dr1.Close()
 Me.Close()
 frm_main.Show()
```

Lets focus on these lines :

```
 Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand("Select * From userscanner WHERE Username = '" & txtbox_username.Text & "' ", Connection)
 command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Dim dr1 As MySqlDataReader
 dr1 = command2.ExecuteReader
```

The above code produces an error stating :

> No current query in datareader.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You called your datareader `dr1` because there is also a `dr2`? Because you can't have two datareaders at the same time. Maybee that is what causes the error.

Comment: but I carefully close my dr. Can I use dr again if I want to? @Eminem

Comment: @Eminem is there any other way to get a the content of a row in my database in put it into a variable?

Comment: You can try and work with a `Using Statement`. Check [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?758091-Error-vb-net-2010) for more information.

Comment: Also, why are you using `ExecuteNonQuery`? You are using a [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466110/using-sql-datareader-to-set-variables-to-a-label?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing a `With` statement here, like `With dr1` right after the `dr1.Read()` line...but I would just change it like this:

`Dim id as Integer = dr1(0)`  
`Dim Username As String = dr1(1)`